# how to make an advance search using elasticseach and query string

Tags: elasticsearch, query-string

I'm creating an advance search using elasticsearch and its **query string** functionality..

so I got some questions about advance queries.. I read [query string document](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) but couldn't find any answer,

when in one query string I search for a normal query and a exact query.. `sales AND "industrial machinery"` the result is different with another query that put two query string in must array...

let me show with an example:

```
"query": {
  "bool":{
    "must":[
      {
         "query_string":{
           "query": "sales* AND \"industrial machinery\"",
           "type": "best_fields",
           "fields":["title", "description"]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**count of result : 56**

```
"query":{
  "bool":{
    "must":[
      {
         "query_string":{
           "query": "sales*",
           "type": "best_fields",
           "fields":["title", "description"]
       },
       {
          "query_string":{
           "query": "\"industrial machinery\"",
           "type": "best_fields",
           "fields":["title", "description"]
       }
    ]
  }
}
```

**count of results: 113**

I know the result of second query is correct, but I don't know why elastic made difference between this two queries..

and how can I get same result with first query? I want to get 113 docs when search with first query.

thanks for helping

Comment: I guess the 2nd query returns results even if it finds sales* on "title" field and "industrial machinery" in  description field. The 1st one returns only records having both in same field. Can you check it?

Comment: @TaniaPetsouka just in one field? or the nested object is OK?

Comment: yes you right @TaniaPetsouka Thanks,  and in nested objects, with 1st query I find all search keywords in one object,